# Finding the max value from an equation using Lagrange multiplier.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Maximize $x^2+y^2$ on the curve. $ x^4+7x^2y^2+y^4=1$

$▽ f = (2x,2y)$

$▽g = (4x^3+14xy^2, 14x^2y+4y^3)$

I use the theorem of lagrange cross product. And I get.

$2x(4y^3+14x^2y)-2y(4x^3+14xy^2)=0$

$\Rightarrow$ $\quad$ $x^2-y^2=0$

---

thus $ x=0, y=0$

---

Plug into constraint

$(0,\pm 1),(\pm1,0)$

Maximize $= 2$

---

This is what I think the answer is, but unfortunately there were more points you can plug to get the maximize does anyone know how to get these extra points I am lost on how to do it.

Comment: Using $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ you should get $x  =y$ or $x=-y$. I don't think you used that yet.

Comment: Which are those extra points?